# What is the purpose of the hold at JNC on the Grand Junction Seven SID?

Tags: sid-star

There is a hold on the Grand Junction Seven SID.

[image: Grand Junction Seven SID]

I would expect it is there so that ATC could hold you until you reach the enroute MEA but there is no written reference.

So, what is the reason for the hold?  It is certainly not obvious from the plate or departure procedure.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what you are asking. Try to keep the question on point and use formatting and images to make your question clear.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the chart, you'll see that after takeoff you will arrive at JNC from either the east or the northeast. Transitions then proceed back in an easterly direction (045 to 113 degrees).  With the possible exception of the Rwy 29 departure with the BRICK transition, the SID requires a course reversal at JNC. The charted hold provides a means and protected airspace for the course reversal.

And as you surmise, some aircraft may require climbing in the hold to reach the MEA.

Comment: I'm a little surprised there's no mention of the hold-in-lieu-of-PT in the textual description.

Comment: Thank you for the response but where did you pick up the idea that it "requires" a course reversal. It may become a useful tool for atc but it is not expressly required that I can see.  The procedure is "thence" but no reference to the reversal.I agree that I may be a tool to be used to climb to the mea but are you saying the course reversal is implied due to direction?  It is not specifically written anywhere.